# In Angular, how do I remove "selected" class from an li and then apply it to a new li?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the code below (click Demo), how do I remove the "selected" class from the "Zero" li item and apply it to the "Two" li item. In other words, how do I first clear the currently selected li and then apply the "selected" class to a new li?

In the Demo code, it appears that the removeClass() gets applied even to the newly selected li. The net result is that none of the li's gets the "selected" class. Also note that if you comment out line 11 of the JS code, both "Zero" and "Two" have the "selected" class. The goal is to only have the "selected" class applied to "Two".

Please advise.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/kejor/8/edit?html,js,output#J:L11)

Comment: This seems like a fix-my-code question. You should try to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. There is no user interaction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [this version](http://jsbin.com/menaravecese/1/edit).  You need to rethink your approach when looking at an angular app.  Your controller shouldn't be doing jquery manipulation like it is. Instead, look at my example and see how all of the the state of the DOM is driven by the scope data state.  I don't need to keep track of the various classes that may or may not be applied to a given element, nor do I even really need to know what the template is doing at all.

Another way to do the selection logic is to have a separate scope variable, `$scope.selected`.  Then you can get rid of the `select()` scope function and just do the following in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items"
    ng-class="{selected: item == selected}"
    ng=click="selected = item">
    {{item.text}}
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks, Wade. That makes a lot of sense. I'm trying it now.